# Make a copy of a branch and rebase it (Git)

Tags: git

Let's say I want to have a copy of code that is not rebased, and a copy that is rebased.

Is this as simple as checking out to a new branch and rebasing it? I ask because I know that under the hood, "branches" are just pointers to commits, so I'm concerned that the underlying commits are "copied by reference" instead of value when checking out to a new branch, meaning that the rebase would affect the original branch as well as the new branch.

Comment: A branch points to a commit. When you rebase a branch, you're creating new commits. This has no impact on other branches, which continue to point at the same commits.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that rebasing made new commits, but that makes sense

Comment: And if you want to keep a branch like the original branch, just setup a different branch on it before you do the rebase: `git checkout the-branch; git branch backup; git rebase blahblah`. So even after `the-branch` has been rebased, `backup` will be pointing to the original commits.

Comment: @eftshift0 that is very much what I had in mind already

Answer (score 1):

A branch is just a pointer — a kind of bookmark. If you are about to rebase `myBranch` onto `otherBranch`, and you want to keep track of what `myBranch` was like before the rebase, one way to do it is simply to make a branch before the rebase. So:

```
# currently on myBranch...
git branch bookmark
git rebase otherBranch
```

Now `myBranch` has been rebased onto `otherBranch` — but `bookmark` has not, and in fact it is *identical* to what `myBranch` looked like *before* the rebase.

However, there's no need to plan ahead so diligently. Even if you forgot to do this, and just went ahead and did the rebase and then slapped your head wishing you had made a bookmark branch first, you can still retrieve the commit that was at the end of `myBranch` before the rebase, simply by looking in the `reflog` — and now you can make the `bookmark` branch on it, after the fact. The `reflog` is Git's "undo" stack!